# Python script - account generator

Tags: python, python-requests

i only started learning python recently and i tried writing an account generator for a random store, just for learning purposes and i have a few questions.

This is my code:

```
import requests
import random
from random import getrandbits
import time

session = requests.session()

url = 'https://chmielna20.pl/en/register'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'}

name = 'John' #enter your name
surname = 'Doe' #enter your surname
email = 'test+{}@gmail.com'.format(getrandbits(40)) #enter your email, dont     change anything after '+'
password = 'Testing1234' #enter your password, minimum 8 characters

times = int(input("[" + (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + "]" + " - Enter the number of account(s) you would like to create: ")))

text_file = open("chmielna accounts.txt", "w")


def create_account():

print("[" + (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) + "]" + " - SUBMITTING INFO.....")
global session
global email

    payload = {
        "Name": name,
        "surname": surname,
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
        "zapoznalem": "on"
}

response = session.post(url, data = payload, headers = headers)

def write():
text_file.write(email + ":" + password + "\n")

if "Success" in response.text:
    print("[" + (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) + "]" +" - SUCCESSFULLY CREATED     ACCOUNT "+email+":"+password)
    write()
else:
    print("[" + (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) + "]" +" - ERROR COULD NOT CREATE "+email+":"+password)

for i in range (times):
create_account()
```

So first question is why am i getting error 'unused variable 'payload'' (in def create_account) and 'undefined variable 'payload'' (in response). I defined payload in def create_account.

Second question is on https://chmielna20.pl/en/register you have to check the box "Zapoznałam/em się z Regulaminem sklepu internetowego i akceptuję jego postanowienia." - how can i do that in python?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I don't know if you've accounted for this, but your indentation is not consistent. When you define a function you need to indent the code underneath that's part of that function. If you've already done that, can you update your post accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem: The indentation inside the function is not correct nor consistent.**

The error is coming from `response = session.post(url, data = payload, headers = headers)` line.

---

### Use this and adjust your code:

```
import requests
import random
from random import getrandbits
import time

session = requests.session()

url = 'https://chmielna20.pl/en/register'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'}

name = 'John' #enter your name
surname = 'Doe' #enter your surname
email = 'test+{}@gmail.com'.format(getrandbits(40)) #enter your email, dont     change anything after '+'
password = 'Testing1234' #enter your password, minimum 8 characters

times = int(input("[" + (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + "]" + " - Enter the number of account(s) you would like to create: ")))
text_file = open("chmielna accounts.txt", "w")

def create_account():
    print("[" + (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) + "]" + " - SUBMITTING INFO.....")
    global session
    global email
    payload = {
        "Name": name,
        "surname": surname,
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
        "zapoznalem": "on"
    }

def write():
    text_file.write(email + ":" + password + "\n")
    if "Success" in response.text:
        print("[" + (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) + "]" +" - SUCCESSFULLY CREATED     ACCOUNT "+email+":"+password)
        write()
    else:
        print("[" + (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) + "]" +" - ERROR COULD NOT CREATE "+email+":"+password)

for i in range (times):
    create_account()
```

**Result:**

```
[00:33:04] - Enter the number of account(s) you would like to create: 5
[00:33:05] - SUBMITTING INFO.....
[00:33:05] - SUBMITTING INFO.....
[00:33:05] - SUBMITTING INFO.....
[00:33:05] - SUBMITTING INFO.....
[00:33:05] - SUBMITTING INFO.....
```

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to return anything.

Comment: It still doesnt work for me, i'm getting
       "[00:26:09] - ERROR COULD NOT CREATE test+797579516032@gmail.com:Testing1234"

I think its because i have to accept terms of conditions on the site to register, does python do that automatically? Or how can i do it?

Comment: @zzex I added the full code. For 5 accounts I get the results that you can see in my answer. Copy paste my code and keep the indentation the same as mine.

Comment: Yes its submitting info but doesn't create an account

Comment: You have not used `write` function. Add your full code and then I can help you more

Answer (score 0):

`***enter code here***`s, 11 months ago
Modified 2 years, 9 months ago
Viewed 7k times

2

i only started learning python recently and i tried writing an account generator for a random store, just for learning purposes and i have a few questions.

This is my code:

import requests
import random
from random import getrandbits
import time

session = requests.session()

url = 'https://chmielna20.pl/en/register'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'}

name = 'John' #enter your name
surname = 'Doe' #enter your surname
email = 'test+{}@gmail.com'.format(getrandbits(40)) #enter your email, dont     change anything after '+'
password = 'Testing1234' #enter your password, minimum 8 characters

times = int(input("[" + (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + "]" + " - Enter the number of account(s) you would like to create: ")))

text_file = open("chmielna accounts.txt", "w")

def create_account():

print("[" + (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) + "]" + " - SUBMITTING INFO.....")
global session
global email

```
payload = {
    "Name": name,
    "surname": surname,
    "email": email,
    "password": password,
    "zapoznalem": "on"
```

}

response = session.post(url, data = payload, headers = headers)

def write():
text_file.write(email + ":" + password + "\n")

if "Success" in response.text:
print("[" + (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) + "]" +" - SUCCESSFULLY CREATED     ACCOUNT "+email+":"+password)
write()
else:
print("[" + (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) + "]" +" - ERROR COULD NOT CREATE "+email+":"+password)

for i in range (times):
create_account()enter link description here

Comment: Please format your code and add indentations